# When adding a decimal such as '1.99', it is shown as 199 in my ASP.NET Core MVC app (decimal is added but without the comma)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

When adding a new transaction, after specifying the transaction value on the textbox and then submitting, the transaction value is equal to the decimal without the dot (in my `AddTransaction` controller, the transaction.value is equal to that).

Html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <form asp-action="AddTransaction" method="post">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Date</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Date" asp-for="Transaction.Date">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Transaction.Date" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" asp-for="Transaction.Name">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Transaction.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <label>Category</label>
                            @{
                                <select id="selectCategory" asp-for="Transaction.CategoryId">
                                    <option value="@category.Id" selected>@category.Name</option>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.CategorySelectList.Where(x => x.Text != category.Name))
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            }
                            <br />
                            <label>Value</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Value" asp-for="Transaction.Value">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Transaction.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <label>Currency</label>
                            <select asp-for="CurrencyObjectJson" asp-items="Model.CurrencySelectList"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

`Transaction` model class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyNativeSymbol { get; set; }
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be positive.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

`AddTransaction` method:

```
public IActionResult AddTransaction(Models.Transaction transaction, CategoryViewModel cvm)
{
    decimal transactionValue = transaction.Value;

    transactionValue = decimal.Parse(transactionValue.ToString());

    var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories();
    var transactions = _transactionService.GetAllTransactions();

    var transactionCategory = categories.Where(c => c.Id == transaction.CategoryId).First();

    transactionCategory.TotalValue += transaction.Value;

    var selectedCurrencyOption = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Currency>(cvm.CurrencyObjectJson);

    transaction.CurrencyCode = selectedCurrencyOption.CurrencyCode;
    transaction.CurrencyNativeSymbol = selectedCurrencyOption.NativeSymbol;

    _transactionService.AddTransaction(transaction);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    Currency currencyObject = new Currency
        {
            CurrencyCode = categories.First().CurrencyCode,
            NativeSymbol = categories.First().CurrencyNativeSymbol,
            Name = string.Empty
        };
    string currencyJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(currencyObject);

    UpdateCurrency(currencyJson);

    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

I tried to add a decimal as value but it didn't work as expected

Comment: Instead of using number for the input's type, `type="number"`, try using decimal, `type="decimal"`

Comment: Sounds like a `Culture` problem to me. You may need to set `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`...

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work sadly. It must be about culture because if I insert a comma it works. Added this to Program.cs and all the actions of my Categories controller.

`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;`

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code running? This smells like a region issue where your local client interface is set up for "." as a decimal separator, but the server locale is using "," as a decimal separator where "." is treated as a thousands separator. This can be an issue with cloud hosting where the locale reflects a different country than you expect. So for instance you type "1.99" where the server locale expects "1,99". The "." would be what it expects to see for something like "1.900,55" vs. "1,900.55" you might expect, where the thousands separator is essentially ignored.

You could try entering "1,99" and see if that stores the value you expect. If it is the locale you should be able to update the locale on your server/machine. If you are dealing with a web application that crosses locales then you need to handle this client side to ensure that any data sent to a server is formatted consistent to what the server expects, or the client informs the server of the locale settings they will be sending and the server can perform the translation with the correct locale.

Edit:

To set an ASP.Net Core's culture, you can force it to use "en-US" for the web server on startup using:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

using `CurrentUICulture` is a carry over for distinguishing front-end culture settings. `Thread.CurrentThread` will just update one executing thread, where ASP.Net Core will be spawning several threads to handle requests so we can instead set the default culture for all threads to ensure it is using what we expect.

Comment: It's running on localhost, and you're right, it works with a comma. I added this to Program.cs and all the actions of my Categories controller but still doesn't work

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

Comment: I have added an update to the answer with the step to update the server's `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Damn, you're good. Thank you really much! It worked.

Comment: @Hiasd, if this was your solution and you appreciate the answer from Steve, then why don't you do the community and Steve a favor and accept the answer?